# Java 9 Modules - Package and Jar difference

Tags: java, python, node.js, module, java-9

In Java we have package, jar concepts to achieve modular programming.
Why Java 9 introduced "Modules" again . What is the difference between these concepts . Looks like , just Python/Node.js and other languages has this module and Java simply follows the same path.

Comment: [This](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html) article may shed some light. Have you seen it already?

Comment: JARs don't really provide modular programming, it's more about packaging code. E.g., you cannot make only a part of a JAR public - if you add a JAR to classpath, all its classes become visible to the application. Modules address this issue. Another big point is the dependencies - a module declares/defines its dependencies (incl. dependencies to the modules of the JRE itself) while a JAR doesn't.